How to change the input source switching pop up back to the bigger one?
I’m now using macOS Sonoma 14.4.1, and I need to work with five languages in my daily life.
Before updating to Sonoma, whenever I switched input sources, a large pop-up would appear in the middle of the screen, clearly indicating the current input source. Like this⬇️

However, after the update, this pop-up only appears when I’m not typing or when the cursor isn’t in a text box. When I switch input sources while typing, a small pop-up appears just below the cursor, which is hard to see, especially on an extended display. This tiny pop-up ⬇️

I’m wondering if anyone knows how to restore the larger pop-up, so it appears regardless of where the cursor is. I’d really appreciate any help, as it would make my workflow much smoother.

To get back the old, large style input menu pop-up input this command into Terminal:
defaults write kCFPreferencesAnyApplication TSMLanguageIndicatorEnabled 0

After that you need to re-launch any applications that will still be showing the old pop-up.
Sources:

https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/21080-alfred-doesnt-show-the-text-cursor-in-macos-sonoma-if-the-redesigned-text-cursor-is-disabled/
https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/236f543b0f9f6509f5fe5878de01e38a?permalink_comment_id=4748936#gistcomment-4748936


Thank you so much!!
